# IdentityServer4: Is it possible to change Authority during runtime?

Tags: identityserver4

In my RP, I define the authority in the ConfigureServices method which is called at startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
    })
        .AddCookie("Cookies")
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
            options.ClientId = "MyClient";
            options.ResponseType = "code id_token"; 

            // some more config
        });
}
```

Is it possible to change the authority later?

Use case: The IdP might be restarted, now listening on a different port or even on a different machine. The RP can find the correct address by asking a service discovery, but can I tell the middleware about the new location of the Authority?

Comment: Did you have any progress with it?